# Не работает форма mail PHP

Tags: email, php, html, форма

Целый день пытаюсь завести эту форму, вроде бы все правильно, но при вводе всех данных в соответствующие поля мне выдает ошибку, что они не все заполнены. Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка.

```
<?

    // Replace this with your own email address
    $to="tes@test.com";

    // Extract form contents
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Validate email address
    function valid_email($str) {
        return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    // Return errors if present
    $errors = "";

    if($name =='') { $errors .= "name,"; }
    if(valid_email($email)==FALSE) { $errors .= "email,"; }
    if($message =='') { $errors .= "message,"; }

    // Send email
    if($errors =='') {

        $headers =  'From: FluidApp <no-reply@fluidapp.com>'. "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $email_subject = "Website Contact Form: $email";
        $message="Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nWebsite: $website \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nMessage:\n\n $message";

        mail($to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "true";

    } else {
        echo $errors;
    }

?>
```

Comment: А сама форма где?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $errors;
```

Тут выдает, что не все? Так указано же, что именно не так. Мне кажется, проблема в том, чего тут нет, ибо скрипт на первый взгляд вроде нормик.

Comment: Залил все на хостинг, захожу в эту форму, все ввожу, а мне пишет, что не все поля заполнены, вот и все. В чем дело, понять не могу.